# Dresser Drawer is Stuck

Tags: stuck

This drawer is stuck in my dresser and won’t come out. I think there’s a screw on the rail that came out and is blocking it but I can’t figure out how to reach the screw to remove it. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the screws work themselves out they can catch on the drawer slides like you suggested. Unfortunately this can be tough to solve. Luckily they are usually protruding a very small amount and that can be overcome by brute force or by gently twisting or applying lateral (sideways) pressure to the dresser to try to change the geometry of the piece while you try to pull the drawer out.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I was able to get it unstuck thanks to your advice 